# Search by key, value or both in array of objects with dynamic fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I got documents with field `entities` which is array of dynamic objects like this

```
{entities: [{propertyA: "asd"}]}
{entities: [{propertyA: "qwe"}, {propertyB: "zxc"}]}
```

I need to be able to find documents by queries like this

```
match: {key: "propertyA"}
match: {value: "zxc"}
match: {propertyA: "qwe"}
```

I tried to generate additional keyword field with all keys and values concatenated and search with wildcard, but wildcard is too slow, may be I need to create some custom analyzer?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that those are 3 different queries you are trying to express?  And if so, what is (for example) the problem with the first one, can you not simply do `{"exists": { "field": "entities.propertyA" }}` ?

Comment: @NicolasGaller no problem with this, also third query could be `"match": {"entities.propertyA": "qwe"}`, but what with second query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) to search against any value

> The copy_to parameter allows you to copy the values of multiple fields into a group field, which can then be queried as a single field.

copy_to  is defined at time of creating mapping.
Since your mapping is dynamic i.e all fields are not known at run time. You can define it as below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "copy_to": "_all"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

above will copy only text fields.

if all fields are known before hand, you can define it in normal mapping, example you will get in documentation.

Query for your case

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "entities.propertyA"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "entities.propertyA": "qwe"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": "zxc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
        "_index" : "index59",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PUIdDn0BLZ9gNW_AoVe7",
        "_score" : 2.3031168,
        "_source" : {
          "entities" : [
            {
              "propertyA" : "qwe"
            },
            {
              "propertyB" : "zxc"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```